# How to password protect email sending in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I am using Outlook 2010 desktop application.

I want to password protect the email sending option so that if anyone tries to send an email using my email account, a password will be prompted (popup) to verify whether it's me.

I heard from some friends something like that I can create a macro,adding a module on my outlook, filter, maybe code it using VB langage or others... and when I leave my desk I must only active this filter or something like that and then nobody could send an email using my email account but I don't know exactly how can I do it... Anybody has an idea please ?

Comment: not sure what this has to do with Excel.  As an alternative, when you walk away from your desktop, why not lock you computer?  That would prevent people from not only sending email, but read your email or doing anything with your local files or anything tied to you account logged in from your computer.  When you get back you just log in again and you are back to your desktop. or whatever application you left running while you were gone.

Comment: @ForwardEd I need more security when I forget to lock my computer

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko yes you could programm a code for protect email sending in Outlook

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MailItem.Send` event. When this event occurs, you can display a dialog that prompts for your password.

Here are the details for this event.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865379.aspx

If the password is incorrect, you set `Cancel=True` to prevent the item from sending. I recommend implementing a timer so that your code doesn't invoke this password prompt while you are actively your system.

I'm assuming you are developer and can take it from here.